# How to to average the counts between parts in SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a bunch of sales ids with associated counts divided into four different groups/parts using ntile funtion and table data looks something like this:

[existing Data of sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ETqf.png)

I would like to write a sql to balance the all four groups to have average counts. if you observe the data, group four having two sales ids with huge volume that should be distributed to other groups as shown below :

[Required data of sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm7c8.png)

SELECT TABLEA.SALESID,TABLEA.COUNT,ntile(4) OVER(ORDER BY null) AS PART NUMBER FROM TABLEA;

Comment: In case you didn't notice, "existing" and "required" images look just the same (or I didn't spot the difference).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out . I modifed it . Kindly have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed number of buckets, you can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
select sales_id,
       cnt,
       part_number,
       bucket
FROM (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (
    sales_id,
    cnt,
    part_number,
    0 AS bucket,
    0 AS b1,
    0 AS b2,
    0 AS b3,
    0 AS b4
  )
  RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
    bucket[1] = 1,
    b1[1] = cnt[1],
    b2[1] = 0,
    b3[1] = 0,
    b4[1] = 0,
    bucket[rn>1] = CASE LEAST(b1[cv()-1], b2[cv()-1], b3[cv()-1], b4[cv()-1])
                   WHEN b1[cv()-1] THEN 1
                   WHEN b2[cv()-1] THEN 2
                   WHEN b3[cv()-1] THEN 3
                   WHEN b4[cv()-1] THEN 4
                   END,
    b1[rn>1] = b1[cv()-1] + CASE bucket[cv()] WHEN 1 THEN cnt[cv()] ELSE 0 END,
    b2[rn>1] = b2[cv()-1] + CASE bucket[cv()] WHEN 2 THEN cnt[cv()] ELSE 0 END,
    b3[rn>1] = b3[cv()-1] + CASE bucket[cv()] WHEN 3 THEN cnt[cv()] ELSE 0 END,
    b4[rn>1] = b4[cv()-1] + CASE bucket[cv()] WHEN 4 THEN cnt[cv()] ELSE 0 END
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (sales_id, cnt, part_number) AS
SELECT  1, 5000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 4000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 3000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 2000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 1000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6,  500, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7,  400, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8,  300, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9,  200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,  100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,   10, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SALES_ID | CNT | PART_NUMBER | BUCKET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4000 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3000 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2000 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 1000 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 500 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 400 | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | 300 | 2 | 4 |
| 9 | 200 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 100 | 1 | 3 |
| 11 | 10 | 1 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UppWDvbd)

Comment: I am trying to understand the code writted using model function and i observed record count is order desc and intially assigned 0 to all buckets . The rest of the code not able to understand . Kindly give brief about it .

Comment: @Shan Exactly as per my pipelined function answer. It iterates over the result set and for each count value, from largest to smallest count. puts it into the emptiest bucket each time.

Comment: Kindly confirm that it will not overwrite the record count values .

Comment: @Shan It is a `SELECT` statement not an `UPDATE` or `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot . it working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PIPELINED` function to split the rows into a fixed number of buckets adding each successive row to the emptiest bucket each time:

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (sales_id, cnt, part_number) AS
SELECT  1, 5000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 4000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 3000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 2000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 1000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6,  500, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7,  400, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8,  300, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9,  200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10,  100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11,   10, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can create a function and supporting types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE bucket_obj AS OBJECT(
  sales_id    NUMBER,
  cnt         NUMBER,
  part_number NUMBER,
  bucket      NUMBER
);

CREATE TYPE bucket_tbl AS TABLE OF bucket_obj;

CREATE FUNCTION generate_buckets(
  i_num_buckets IN NUMBER
) RETURN bucket_tbl PIPELINED
IS
  v_buckets SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
  v_bucket PLS_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION emptiest_bucket RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    v_sz  PLS_INTEGER := v_buckets(1);
    v_idx PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 2 .. v_buckets.COUNT LOOP
      IF v_buckets(i) < v_sz THEN
        v_sz := v_buckets(i);
        v_idx := i;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN v_idx;
  END;
BEGIN
  v_buckets.EXTEND(i_num_buckets);
  FOR i IN 1 .. i_num_buckets LOOP
    v_buckets(i) := 0;
  END LOOP;

  FOR rw IN (SELECT sales_id, cnt, part_number
             FROM   table_name
             ORDER BY cnt DESC)
  LOOP
    v_bucket := emptiest_bucket();
    PIPE ROW (bucket_obj(rw.sales_id, rw.cnt, rw.part_number, v_bucket));
    v_buckets(v_bucket) := v_buckets(v_bucket) + rw.cnt;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then the statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(generate_buckets(4)) t
ORDER BY bucket, sales_id;
```

Outputs:

| SALES_ID | CNT | PART_NUMBER | BUCKET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4000 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3000 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 500 | 2 | 3 |
| 9 | 200 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 100 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2000 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 1000 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 400 | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | 300 | 2 | 4 |
| 11 | 10 | 1 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TT-Vz6OS)

Answer (score 0):

For the fun, with a recursive query:

```
with data(sales_id, cnt, part_number) as (
    SELECT  1, 5000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  2, 4000, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  3, 3000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  4, 2000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  5, 1000, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  6,  500, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  7,  400, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  8,  300, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  9,  200, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10,  100, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 11,   10, 1 FROM DUAL
),
rdata as (
    select row_number() over(order by cnt desc, sales_id) as rn, d.*
    from data d
),
cte(rn, sales_id, cnt, part_number, b1, b2, b3, b4, bucket) as
(
    select d.rn, d.sales_id, d.cnt, d.part_number, d.cnt as b1, 0 as b2, 0 as b3, 0 as b4,
        1 as bucket
    from rdata d
    where rn = 1
    
    union all
    
    select r.rn, r.sales_id, r.cnt, r.part_number, 
        case 
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b1
                then b1+r.cnt
            else b1
        end,
        case 
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b2
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b1
                then b2+r.cnt
            else b2
        end,
        case 
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b3
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b1
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b2
                then b3+r.cnt
            else b3
        end,
        case 
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b4
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b1
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b2
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b3
                then b4+r.cnt
            else b4
        end,
        case 
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b1 then 1
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b2
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b1 then 2
            when least(b1, b2, b3, b4) = b3
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b1
                and least(b1, b2, b3, b4) <> b2
                then 3
            else 4
        end
    from cte c
    join rdata r on r.rn = c.rn + 1
    
)
select sales_id, cnt, part_number, bucket from cte
order by bucket, sales_id
;
```

| sales_id | cnt | part_number | bucket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 4000 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3000 | 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 500 | 2 | 3 |
| 9 | 200 | 1 | 3 |
| 10 | 100 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2000 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 1000 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 400 | 2 | 4 |
| 8 | 300 | 2 | 4 |
| 11 | 10 | 1 | 4 |